# sed caret ^ ignored in python running in Cygwin?

Tags: python, sed, cygwin, dos2unix

I have a file that I'm trying to run a "sed" command on, but I'm having trouble executing it within Python 3.10.1 while I'm running it on Cygwin 3.5.1.

The file I'm working on is very simple, it looks like this:

```
(Distance competency)
 1. Approximately how long does it take for light from the Sun to reach Earth?

 1 8 minutes 
 2 10 minutes 
 3 6 minutes
```

There is a space at the beginning of each line that I'm trying to get rid of, a relatively simple task for sed and a regex search and replace using this:

```
sed -i 's/^[ \t]*//g' ./myFile
```

When I run this at the Cygwin command line, I get exactly what I want, however I'm writing this in a Python script, and when I execute the following lines:

```
sedStatement = "sed -i 's/^[ \t]*//g' ./myFile"
os.system(sedStatement)
```

I get the following output:

```
(Distancecompetency) 
1.ApproximatelyhowlongdoesittakeforlightfromtheSuntoreachEarth?

18minutes
210minutes
36minutes
```

So instead of the caret "^" being recognized at all, it looks like it's being ignored and all of the spaces are being replaced with nothing, when what I wanted replaced was "the beginning of the line"+"space" with "nothing". So it looks like this...

```
(Distance competency)
1. Approximately how long does it take for light from the Sun to reach Earth?

1 8 minutes
2 10 minutes
3 6 minutes
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what's causing this?  I noticed I had a "^M" as an end of line marker, but I'm not sure that's the issue.  I went ahead and installed "dos2unix" and ran this command, but it didn't get rid of the "^M" end of line markers.

```
    unix2dos -iso -n myFile myFile2
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm still relatively new to Python.

Comment: idk why the `^` would be ignored but in regards to just the sed command - a) get rid of the `g` since you want to do 1 replacement, b) change `/^[ \t]/` to just `/ /` since you know each line starts with a single blank char and THAT is what you want to remove. Also, you ran `unix2dos` when what you should have run is `dos2unix`,

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, though it's likely the line endings did have something to do with it, except you want to be running `dos2unix` not `unix2dos`.  But if you're using Python why even run sed with os.system?  Python already has the facilities for you to do this.  Also note you should have use a "raw" string `sedStatement = "sed -i r's/^[ \t]*//g' ./myFile"` because the `\t` also means a literal tab character in python.  Though this wouldn't be the problem.